# Line instead of dashed line xml drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to draw a dashed line with this code:

```
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">

    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000000"
            android:dashWidth="6dp"
            android:dashGap="10dp"/>

    <size android:height="5dp" />

</shape>
```

But on some devices, for instance runnning android 4.0.3, it looks like a normal line instead of a dashed one.
What is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add this android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in application manifest body, work for me, but it is not the best way of solving this question

Answer (score 0):

I also has problems with dashed line drawable.
Finally, I got desperate and fixed it with a simple hack. This TextView looks exactly like vertical dashed line.

```
<TextView
         android:text="_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"
         android:rotation="270"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image: dashline line]